# How to initialize static fields in C++?

Tags: c++

I need a class with static `std::vector<int> simples` (first N simple numbers). I created it in static method `__init__`, which is called before any instance of MyClass is created:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        /* I need to use MyClass::simples here */
        printf("%d\n", (int)MyClass::simples.size());
        /* But I get the error here :( */
    }

    static void __init__(int N)
    {
        simples.push_back(2);
        /* ...
           here I compute first N simple numbers and fill 
           MyClass::simples with them
        */
    }

private:
    static std::vector<int> simples;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass::__init__(1000);
    MyClass var;

    return 0;
}
```

But when I tried to use this vector in construction, I get `undefined reference to 'MyClass::simples'` error. How to solve my problem?

Comment: Using double underscore in names [is reserved to the compiler/standard library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/440558).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a static member in C++, you need to write it two times: first in class definition as you did:

```
static std::vector<int> simples;
```

And then outside (preferably in an external .cpp file):

```
std::vector<int> MyClass::simples;
```

If you know about C language, this can help you: static members in C++ are comparable from global variables in C: defined as a prototype in .h file included whenever you need it, and value initialized in one .c/.cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the static data member outside the class

```
std::vector<int> MyClass::simples;
```

Within the class definition it is only declared.